# How to display header in a Series of pandas?

Tags: pandas, header, series

data is a  instance of pandas.core.series.Series.

```
 >>> type(data)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> data
1    002728
2    002142
3    002284
Name: scode, dtype: object
```

How to display it as follows ?

```
>>> data
     scode
1    002728
2    002142
3    002284
Name: scode, dtype: object
```

Comment: `data.to_frame()`, if you want header convert series to a dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a dataframe. Two options on how to do so:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data = data.to_frame()
print(data)
   scode
0  002728
1  002142
2  002284
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)
 scode
0  002728
1  002142
2  002284
```

The only practical difference between a single column dataframe and a series that I can think of off the top of my head is indexing. If you want to select the first element of a series... you can do it as follows:

```
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data[0]
# 002728
```

But for a one column dataframe, data[0] wouldn't work. Here's what you'd need to do to get the value in the first row:

```
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data = data.to_frame()
data.iloc[0,0]
# 002728
```

And to get the value in the ith row

```
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data = data.to_frame()
print(data.iloc[i,0])
```

You could use

```
data = pd.Series(['002728','002142','002284'], name = 'scode')
data = data.to_frame()
data.iloc[i]
```

but that would give you a series containing just the value in the ith row.

```
print(type(data.iloc[0,0]))
#<class 'str'>
print(type(data.iloc[0]))
#pandas.core.series.Series
```

If your series consisted of numerical values...here's how a vectorized method such as multiplication would work:

```
numbers = pd.Series([1,3,5,7], name = 'numbers')
print(numbers)
# 0  1
1    3
2    5
3    7
Name: numbers, dtype: int64


print(numbers*3)
#0    3
1     9
2    15
3    21
Name: numbers, dtype: int64
```

For a single column dataframe with the same numerical values as the series above:

```
numbers = pd.Series([1,3,5,7], name = 'numbers')
numbers = numbers.to_frame()
print(numbers)
#   numbers
0        1
1        3
2        5
3        7

print(numbers*3)

#   numbers
0        3
1        9
2        15
3        21
```